# Connecting to my local docker Database Instance from Table Plus

Tags: wordpress, docker, table-plus

I have created a local docker wordpress instance and I am trying to connect to the database with a SQL Client (in my case TablePlus) but I am having trouble.

I created the docker containers from a docker-compose.yml file shown here:

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8028:80"
       - "8029:8029"

     volumes:
       - ./themes/travelmatic:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/yadayada


     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       VIRTUAL_HOST: leasepilot.local

volumes:
    db_data:
```

I have tried any comibindation of wordpress and somewordpress in these fields:
[image]

I also have the option to connect over SSH but I don't feel I would need to do that?

1) What is the best way to debug this type of issue?
2) What are the creds? lol

Comment: Without a `ports:` declaration, your database will be inaccessible from outside of Docker.  Finding the credentials is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just as David has suggested in his comment, you need to add port mapping in docker-compose.yml. So, your modified docker-compose.yml would be something like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"   
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8028:80"
       - "8029:8029"

     volumes:
       - ./themes/travelmatic:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/yadayada


     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       VIRTUAL_HOST: leasepilot.local

volumes:
    db_data:
```

And you have already provided the creds in the docker-compose.yml in environment variables.

Answer (score 21):

There is another bit of information that should be added to the Praveen answer.
If you have already mysql installed locally, on your computer/laptop, settings the db ports to:

```
- "3306:3306"
```

it won't work because TablePlus will connect to your local mysql instance.
Instead you should set your Docker mysql on a different published port and access that from TablePlus.

For example, set these ports on your Dockerfile (published port is **3356**):

```
"3356:3306"
```

Then set the same port on TablePlus:
[image]