# Unable to connect to a running Laravel Sail Docker project with TablePlus (role does not exist)

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker, laravel-sail

I created a new Laravel project and installed Sail with `composer require laravel/sail --dev` followed by `php artisan sail:install` and `sail up` to get the project up and running in Docker.

By doing these actions my .env file changed from

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_docker
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

to

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=pgsql
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=laravel_docker
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

And now I got two running Docker containers:

```
laravel-docker_laravel.test_1
laravel-docker_pgsql_1
```

I'm able to run the basic user migration with `sail artisan migrate`.

Next up I want to connect Tableplus (or Postico) with my Postgresql database running in Docker. Therefore I filled in the following information:

[image: Tableplus screenshot]

When trying to connect I got ERROR FATAL: role "sail" does not exist.

Can someone help me out?

Edit 1: Adding a screenshot from some terminal commands. I can connect to the database in the docker container, see a list of the tables and get a table with all the rows from the users table (inserted with a seeder using Laravel Sail)

[image: CLI screenshot]

Edit 2: `docker-compose ps`

[image: docker-compose up screenshot]

Comment: What you get changing the host/socket from localhost to pgsql?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Error message 'could not translate host name "pgsql" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known'

Comment: just to discard ... does the .env file setup works?  that is, laravel can connect to the db?

Comment: The docker containers are running and I was able to migrate the basic user table with sail artisan migrate so I assume it works. I can do an extra check. Give me a minute to write some code to store a user

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Yes, I'm able to run a seeder and create users

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Added a screenshot of my terminal

Comment: Can you show us what `docker-compose ps` looks like ? Also, this should not change anything but instead of using `localhost` try `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @matiaslauriti Changing localhost tot 127.0.0.1 gives the same result ~ FATAL:  role "sail" does not exist. I've added a screenshot with the result of `docker-compose ps`, see Edit 2.

Comment: Just for testing, try to connect to `template1` or `template0` instead of `laravel_docker`

Comment: @matiaslauriti When trying to connect to template0 I get the following error `database "template0" is not currently accepting connections`. template1 is accessible 'You are now connected to database "template1" as user "sail".'

Comment: @Thore I have no idea about Postgre but I think it is related to some permissions, as you can see on your screenshot

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57411287/connecting-to-my-local-docker-database-instance-from-table-plus) I found a working solution.

Changing to a different port in the `docker-compose.yml` file fixed the issue.

Before:

```
pgsql:
    image: 'postgres:13'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
```

After:

```
pgsql:
    image: 'postgres:13'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5632}:5432'
```

After changing the port number to `5632` in TablePlus I'm able to connect to the database.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem "role "sail" does not exist". In this case we need to use command `./vendor/bin/sail down -v` to delete the existing Docker volume data. After that you can do `./vendor/bin/sail up` command.